# Migrating from ADFS 1.1 to ADFS 2.0

Tags: migration, adfs

We're planning to migrate from ADFS 1.1 to ADFS 2.0 and I've been researching for a whitepaper on the subject with out much luck.

Any one has a reference to such?

Answer (score 2):

This should help . http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678035(WS.10).aspx